# Redirecting all sub-sub pages to another subpage using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I've a older site running in Apache Server which is already indexed in Google. I wish to redirect all those indexed links to my new site (As the older pages are not existing any more.)

So i wish to redirect all my sub-sub pages to my new root page

I've pages like follows

```
http://itdost.com/answer-now/Aerobics
http://itdost.com/answer-now/HTML
http://itdost.com/answer-now/Culture
```

I use the following redirect code for each one

```
Redirect 301 /answer-now/Engineering http://www.itdost.com/questions/
Redirect 301 /answer-now/Food http://www.itdost.com/questions/
Redirect 301 /answer-now/ASP http://www.itdost.com/questions/
```

But as the site structure is big, i wish to do it in a single line instead of writing a line for each redirect

Some thing like the following.

```
Redirect 301 /answer-now/% http://www.itdost.com/questions/
```

But the above code does not seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use regex better to use mod_rewrite which is more powerful than mod_alias.

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^answer-now(/.*|)$ http://www.itdost.com/questions/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/answer-now/ http://www.itdost.com/questions/
```

Comment: I tried the above but it redirects to the following page instead of questions "http://www.itdost.com/HTML?qa-rewrite=answer-now/HTML"

Comment: Do you have any more redirect / rewrite rules? I assume you're using an .htaccess file?